# codigo que da tu peso en otro planeta

Tags: java

Resulta que estoy haciendo un codigo que da tu peso en otro planeta pero a la hora de siempre imprimir el resultado de tu peso en  otro planeta siempre me da 0

```
          int opcion; 
           double p;
           double mercurio = 0.38; 
           
           double peso = 0;
           double resultado = peso * mercurio;
           ;
            
           while(!salir){
                
               System.out.println("1.    Mercurio");
               ;
               System.out.println("8.    Salir");
                
               System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
               opcion = sn.nextInt();
                
               switch(opcion){
                   case 1:
                       System.out.println("Has seleccionado  Mercurio digita tu peso :");
                       peso = sn.nextDouble();
                        
                       System.out.println("Tu peso en mercurio es"+resultado);
                       break;
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega tu código como texto formateado en lugar de imagen. Es más sencillo para ti copiarlo desde tu editor y pegarlo acá y, a su vez, nos simplifica el hecho de probarlo. Es más conveniente copiarlo que transcribirlo desde la imagen.

Comment: Pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Tal como está actualmente, suena a _clickbait_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener en cuenta que el código se ejecuta de arriba hacia abajo en orden (salvo en el caso de bucles, funciones, etc.), por lo que cuando calculas el resultado en `double resultado = peso * mercurio;` peso vale 0, pues le has asignado ese valor justo en la línea anterior `double peso = 0;` para que se use el valor de peso obtenido con el `nextDouble` deberías calcular el resultado después, por ejemplo:

```java
int opcion; 
double p;
double mercurio = 0.38; 
           
double peso = 0;
double resultado;
            
while(!salir){
    System.out.println("1.    Mercurio");
    ...
    System.out.println("8.    Salir");

    System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
    opcion = sn.nextInt();
                
    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Has seleccionado  Mercurio digita tu peso :");
            peso = sn.nextDouble();
            resultado = peso * mercurio;
            System.out.println("Tu peso en mercurio es"+resultado);
            break;
        ...
```

Postdata: Para la próxima intenta formatear el código de manera que sea más legible y facilite su comprensión, y en el título pon una descripción breve de tu problema. Esto facilitará a los usuarios ayudarte.